# Dimension of $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Why is the group $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ of dimension $n^{2}$?

Comment: The group $M(n, \mathbb{R})$ of $n\times n$ matrices has dimension $n^2$. Why? It's easy to show that $M(n, \mathbb{R})$ a vector space. Any element $\in M(n, \mathbb{R})$ can be written in terms of a sum of $n^2$ matrices $B_{ij}$ where the entry $i,j)$ of $B_{ij} = 1$, and zero otherwise. You can show that the set $\{B_{ij}\}$ is a basis of $M(n, \mathbb{R})$, and hence $M(n, \mathbb{R})$ has dimension $n^2$. $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is a subset of $M(n, \mathbb{R})$ under the determinant map. It has the same dimension by Steve's answer below.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is an open submanifold of the set of $n$ by $n$ matrices, which is a vector space of dimension $n^2$.

Comment: Is there are more elementary way to see this though?

Comment: @198203: Isn't that plenty elementary already? It's about the most elementary imaginable argument that can reach the relevant definition of "dimension" at all.

Comment: How many basis elements does an $n$ by $n$ matrix have? Certainly it must be $n^2$... take the obvious basis: a single entry in each matrix to be $1$ and all others to be $0$. Do this $n \cdot n$ times, one for each position in the matrix.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not seeing it, but why does an open submanifold of a vector space must have the dimension of that vector space?

Comment: Think of an open ball in $\mathbb R^2$, perhaps that would help? This ball clearly has dimension $2$. Now the same ideas go for an open submanifold of $M(n,\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Basically, the determinant is a continuous function from the $n\times n$ matrices to $\mathbb R$, and the invertible ones are the ones with non-zero determinant, so $GL(n)=det^{-1}(\mathbb {R}\setminus 0)$. Since $\mathbb R\setminus 0$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$, $GL(n)$ has to be an open subset of the set of all matrices.

Comment: @198203 Do you know the definition of the dimension of a manifold? Once you have the definition, the fact that an open submanifold of an $n$-manifold has dimension $n$ is essentially immediate. What's non-trivial and requires work is the proof that the notion of the dimension of a manifold is well-defined.

Answer (score 13):

You should notice that the determinant is a continuous map  $f:M(n,\mathbb{R})\equiv\mathbb{R}^{n^2}\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(X)=\det(X)$

Then note that

$$GL(n, \mathbb{R})=f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$$

How the pre-image by continuous map of open set is an open set then $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ whose dimension is $n^2$.

(I am here using that an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ has $k$-dimension.)

Comment: How is, by the way, the dimension of an open set defined ? I am wondering because i am familiar with dimensions of vectorspaces etc. but not this.

Comment: If a manifold as a topological space is locally homeomorphic to $R^n$ then its dimension is $n$. We can also think about the Haussdorf Dimension.

Comment: Why does the open set of $R^{n^2}$  has the dimension $R^{n^2}$? If n=2, $\{(x,y,0,0):x,y \in \Bbb R\} $ has basis $(1,0,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0,0)$ .

Comment: @math112358 Your example is not open in $R^4$. Intuitively if a set is open in $R^n$ then it contains a $R^n$ ball and this this ball can't be isomorphic to any lower dimensional space.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry people misunderstood your question. You are clearly asking about dimension in terms of linear algebra and not in terms of manifolds.

The set $GL(n)$ is not a subspace. To see this, take any invertible matrix $A$, then $-A$ is also invertible. But $A-A=0$ is obviously not invertible, thus $GL(n)$ is not a vector subspace for any $n$ so it makes no sense to talk about it's dimension in terms of independent vectors.

However, GL(n) is what is known as a submanifold which means that although $GL(n)$ is not a vector space, you can "locally" (i.e. around some neighborhood of any point in the set) imbue a vector space structure. But this isn't something you should worry about in linear algebra.

Comment: I doubt the OP is still wondering this after ~10 years later lol

Comment: *You are clearly asking about dimension in terms of linear algebra and not in terms of manifolds* Why do you believe that?

Comment: @DionelJaime, the OP is not the only one interested in this answer, that is a possible answer at all. I got here via search engine.